# Filled contour plot for x, y, temp data from a file using python matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a file containing coordinate locations x, y and corresponding Temperature at that location. The first two columns are x and y coordinate location and the 3rd column is temperature. I cannot upload the whole file.

The x and y coordinates are not equally spaced. It comes from unstructured mesh.

I need to get a filled contour plot of the data above.

I tried the following to get it to work.
First, I created a list for the x coordinates, y coordinates and temperature. Then I converted them to numpy arrays as shown below. I then used meshgrid to create the underlying grid upon which I wanted to superimpose the temperatures.

```
x = np.asarray(x)
y = np.asarray(y)
temp = np.asarray(temp)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.contourf(X, Y, temp)
plt.show()
```

I keep getting an error as shown below.

`TypeError: Input z must be 2D, not 1D`

I understand that the dimensions of `temp` cannot be changed.

Could it be done? What changes I would need to make to get a filled contour plot

Using python 3.10

Comment: Have you seen "tricontourf"?

Comment: @fdireito Thanks a lot. You just saved me a ton of time. Have a great day. I will post the solution.

Answer (score 2):

@fdireito posted the right answer in the comments.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri

triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
tcf = ax1.tricontourf(triang, temp)
fig1.colorbar(tcf)
ax1.set_title('Contour Plot of Temperatures')
```

Demo of tricontour  can be found in the link below.
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/tricontour_demo.html